# Populate phpMyAdmin table with java list

Tags: java, mysql, sql, list

I'm trying to populate a table with data in phpMyAdmin thanks to a java code. And i'm facing an issue to fill one of my columns with a list of strings. Here my code :

```
for(Wallpaper w : wallpapersList){                
                if(w != null){ 

                    id = w.getId();
                    preview = w.getPreviewScreen();
                    fullscreen = w.getFullScreen();
                    size = w.getSize();
                    tagsList = w.getTags();  
                }                 
                String insertQuery = " insert into wallpapers (id, preview, fullscreen, size, tags)"
                    + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

                preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
                preparedStmt.setString (1, id);
                preparedStmt.setString (2, preview);
                preparedStmt.setString (3, fullscreen);
                preparedStmt.setString (4, size);
                if(!tagsList.isEmpty()){
                    for(String tag : tagsList){
                        preparedStmt.setString (5, tag);
                    }
                }

                // execute the preparedstatement
                preparedStmt.execute();
```

So here i have a list of strings with my "tagsList" when it's empty return "no tags" that's ok, this value can be set in my table, and sometimes "tagsList" can contains one or several items but when i try to insert several items for one sql insertion query thanks to my loop 'for' just the last one is inserted.

My question is how can i insert list of strings for one insertion in a column ?

In phpMyAdmin, in my table, field tags is a VARCHAR, i don't know if it's the wrong type or not ? Or maybe if it's my loop 'for' which is not suitable for this work.
I saw a .setArray(..) instead of .setString(..), maybe i have to get this ? But i would like to know before it's possible to manage this case with a simple List of strings.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Databases don't store arrays or lists in fields, they just store singular values per line and have multiple lines for multiple values.

There are at least three ways to solve this:

1. Create a new table for tags and have a many-to-many relationship between wallpapers table and tags table. This would be the elegant way to solve the issue using the database for what it's designed to do.
2. List the tags as a single String, separating different items with a separator character (for instance *"tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4"*). This would be the lazy and ugly way to solve it.
3. Serialize your data structure and save it as binary data in DB. This would be quite overkill for a list of Strings though.

Personally I'd got with 1, since that will for instance allow you to search wallpapers by their tags straight from the DB and use its strengths. But if you can't change the table design, then you'll have to go with either 2 or 3 and pull off all the logic on your code.

Comment: Thanks for this complete answer.